# How do I pass a dependency to a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a class that is intended to serve as a repository for making AJAX requests using axios:

```js
export default class SomeRepository {
  getEncryptedValue (value) {
    return axios.get('http://localhost/api/v1/encrypt')
  }
}
```

And I have a component that calls this repository's method inside the `methods` property in the component, like so:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import SomeRepository from '@/classes/SomeRepository'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      value: '',
      result: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    encrypt () {
      let someRepo = new SomeRepository()

      someRepo.getEncryptedValue(this.value)
        .then(response => {
          this.result = response.data.result
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I pass `SomeRepository` as a dependency? My goal is that I want to mock it in my unit tests.

I am looking for a straightforward solution, preferably one that does not involve third-party libraries or boilerplate.

I've tried also doing:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import SomeRepository from '@/classes/SomeRepository'

Vue.use(SomeRepository)
// and
Vue.use(new SomeRepository())
```

which clearly don't work (honestly, I didn't expect them to). I also tried following this article https://codeburst.io/dependency-injection-with-vue-js-f6b44a0dae6d but I did not really like the approach of having to create a mixin every time I want to use a dependency.

I've also considered passing it as a prop, but was not sure where to instantiate the object before passing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of ways to mock functions. The most simplistic that I have found is simply accepting dependencies as parameters of a function and replace the function to use in your tests.

## Example of Method

```
// Function
function func(dependency) {
  dependency.use()
}

// In App
func(dependency) // -> runs dependency.use

// In Tests
func(mockDependency) // -> runs mocked dependency.use
```

## Your Example

Once you know this method you can do a ton of different versions of it but to show a super simple version.

```
encrypt() {
  this._encrypt(SomeRepository)
}
_encrypt (SomeRepository) {
  let someRepo = new SomeRepository()

  someRepo.getEncryptedValue(this.value)
    .then(response => {
      this.result = response.data.result
    })
}
```

You would test _encrypt with the mock dependency.

You can also do something like this.

```
encrypt (_SomeRepository=SomeRepository) {
  let someRepo = new _SomeRepository()

  someRepo.getEncryptedValue(this.value)
    .then(response => {
      this.result = response.data.result
    })
}
```

If you pass in the mocked version it will use that if you do not it will use the real one.
The idea is to use this method however you see fit, but I think you get the idea. It is super simple no magic and no libraries needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Vue plugin
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html
Then you can access it via e.g. `this.$someDeps`

For unit testing, you can mock it easily using Vue Test Utils https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks